# Text anchor in Views - how to?

Tags: views, navigation

I have created a glossary with views. The View (page) contains all published nodes of the content type "glossary-term". This content type consists of only Title and Body field. The view alphabetically lists the entire content of the nodes. On this view page I attempt to put references in the form of anchor links like this:

Term A

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem **Term C** ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Term B

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum **Term A** lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Term C

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem **Term B** ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

In my CKEditor I can only insert anchors within nodes. For example, I could create an anchor in node "Term A" and reference it to the title of "Term A". But this obviously doesn't make sense. I need to reference to another node on the views page.

Hope you understand what I mean. Does somebody know how to accomplish that?

Comment: It seems you're looking for the [Scroll to destination anchors](https://www.drupal.org/project/scroll_to_destination_anchors) module.Did you check that?

Comment: Thanks. I already saw this module. As I understood it just alters the "jump-effect" into a smooth scroll. This isn't what I asked. But I recognized that the example code has a link target #block-system-main. Is it generally possible to link an anchor to a id-class? That whould resolve my problem.

Comment: If you don't mind having the embedded terms link to the view terms when viewed from a node page, then writing your own text filter will work. You will need to load all the Terms, and do a regex replace in the filter, replacing with an anchor with fragment identifier. [Drupal Text Formats 102: Developing custom filters](http://pingv.com/blog/drupal-text-formats-102-developing-custom-filters). Probably 10 - 12 lines of code. And it frees you from inserting links manually.